# Is there a better way to initalize pointers in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Below I have a bit of code for implementing Huffman compression.
What I was curious about was if I could initialize the `left` and `right` pointers without including `cstdlib`, or rather, if I could initialize an empty memory location for storing the `left` and `right` without using malloc.

Also, in my combine function, I do not want to use `"NULL"` for the string parent node of my left and right, but would rather have an empty string. Will I have to make a new constructor for this? I get an error (`basic_string::_M_construct null not valid`) when I replace `"NULL"` with nullptr.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

#ifndef PRIORITY_NODE
#define PRIORITY_NODE

namespace Huffman
{
  class PriorityNode
  {
    private:
      std::string key; // The character sequence to compress
      long frequency = 0;  // The frequency of the character sequence
      PriorityNode* left = (PriorityNode*)malloc(sizeof(PriorityNode));
      PriorityNode* right = (PriorityNode*)malloc(sizeof(PriorityNode));
    
    public:
      PriorityNode(std::string k, long f): frequency(f), key(k){};
      std::string getKey() const{ return key;}
      long getFrequency() const{ return frequency;}
      void setLeft(const PriorityNode& left){*this->left = left;}
      void setRight(const PriorityNode& right){*this->right = right;}
      PriorityNode& getLeft() const{ return *left;}
      PriorityNode& getRight() const{ return *right;}
      friend PriorityNode combine(const PriorityNode& lhs, const PriorityNode& rhs)
      {
        long ret_freq = lhs.getFrequency() + rhs.getFrequency();
        PriorityNode ret = PriorityNode("NULL", ret_freq);
        ret.setLeft(lhs);
        ret.setRight(rhs);
        return ret;
      };
  };
}

#endif
```

Comment: You should show some code that is using `PriorityNode`. More likely than not, you have [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) because for example `left` is initially pointing to raw memory, but then `*this->left = left;` assumes that `left` is pointing to a constructed object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a couple of points.

1. `key` is a string, not a pointer. It makes no sense to set it to `nullptr`, i am guessing `"NULL"`, is just a stand in for when the `key` has no value. Instead of this, just use an empty string `""`.
2. You should try to avoid this manual memory management for several reasons. First of all you have no destructor, so your memory that you `malloc` is never `free`ed meaning you have a memory leak. Secondly, you allocate memory for the sub nodes, even if you do not need to. I would suggest something more like the following:

   ```
    class PriorityNode {
    private:
      ...
      std::shared_ptr<PriorityNode> left, right; // Default constructs to nullptr   
      ...
      friend PriorityNode combine(const std::shared_ptr<PriorityNode> lhs, 
          const std::shared_ptr<PriorityNode> rhs) {
        PriorityNode ret = PriorityNode("", ret_freq);
        ret.setLeft(lhs);
        ret.setRight(rhs);
        return ret;
      };
   ```

Comment: Question: Why does the parent node have a key with no value? I suspect the type system here has become flawed.

Comment: @MooingDuck it's for the Huffman encoding.
It's so that no encoding is a prefix of another encoding https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding

Comment: I've implemented a Huffman encoding, and it does not require a node class object with a NULL key.

Comment: @MooingDuck oops, what do you mean by `type system`?

Comment: The "Type system" is the classes you create, and should generally make it impossible to have invalid data.  I'd usually expect something like this, with a separate `RootNode` and `DataNode` types. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/108f8e099addbab7  Also note: no `new`, no `malloc`, and no memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

The empty string is `""`. You can pass that to the existing constructor. `std::string` doesn't distinguish empty strings and NULL pointers like C strings. It is not allowed to initialize an `std::string` with a NULL pointer. If you need a separate null state, use `std::optional<std::string>`.